# MobSF installation error - Error while creating virtual environment

Tags: security

I am encountering below error while trying to install MobSF in Windows 10 system.
**Error: Command '['C:\Users\diksh\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\Scripts\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.**

I have installed the requirements as mentioned in the requirements document. But it gives error while creating virtual environemnt. Please find the output as below on running setup.bat file. [image]

Kindly provide a solution to resolve the issue.

Comment: Had this come up this morning and can't figure it out. @user3288940 have you found a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.9.9 and my broken command `python -m venv venv`.

I'm not sure of the exact issue as I am new to python. From this old [article](https://codeghar.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/virtualenv-with-python-3-using-venv/) I was able to get it to work without pip by adding the --without-pip flag.

```
python -m venv venv --without-pip
```

Another [article](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1/) suggests that it may be a broken pyenv but in my case I'm fairly certain it's a setup issue or I need to update something.